# Using escape characters in shell

Tags: regex, shell

While reading about `Escape characters` in shell I tried an example -

> echo "The balance for user $USER is: \$5:00"

and it gave the output

> The balance for user me is: $5.00

But when I tried using the escape character `\` with a tab `\t` or a newline `\n`, it didn't seem to work. I tried using it in double quotes (escape characters retain their meaning in the double quotes) but it still didn't work.

> echo "The balance for user $USER is:\t\$5:00"

doesn't give the output

> The balance for user me is:    $5:00

Instead the output was -

> The balance for user vyadav is:\t$5:00

Comment: "Why does it not work?" -- because the shell never does and never did expand `"\t"` into a tab character inside double quotes. Bash will do that inside of `$'\t'` style quotes, but those are different. `echo "\t"` works on systems with XSI-compliant `echo` commands because the `echo` command -- not the shell parsing/preprocessing -- expands the sequence; similarly for `echo -e "\t"` on systems with GNU extensions.

Comment: I don't get it, what does `Shell` expand and what does the command `echo`? `~` is expanded by `Shell` right? and so are wildcards like `*`.

Comment: Yes, tilde expansion and glob expansion are both done by the shell. The only expansions `echo` supports are backslash-escape sequences, and even then only some versions of echo (which is why it's better to use `printf`, since its behavior is consistent between versions). See the **OPERANDS** sections of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html for a list of the backslash-escape sequences an XSI-compliant `echo` will expand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`echo` command doesn't expand **backslash escapes** without `-e` option.

You can use `echo -e` (please note that this is a **gnu extension** and not very portable):

```
echo -e "The balance for user $USER is:\t\$5:00"
The balance for user anubhava is:   $5:00
```

As per `help echo`:

```
-e  enable interpretation of the following backslash escapes
```

Or better to use `printf`:

```
printf "The balance for user %s is:\t\$%s\n" "$USER" "5:00"
```

Or

```
printf 'The balance for user %s is:\t$%s\n' "$USER" "5:00"

The balance for user anubhava is:   $5:00
```

Comment: @yadav_vi: Where did you see extended grep in my answer?

Comment: In the `printf` case, expanding `$USER` inside the format string is poor practice; the format string should always be given single-quoted: `printf 'The balance for user %s is:\t$%s\n' "$USER" "5:00"`; this way format string attacks (which, granted, aren't known to exist in the bash implementation of printf) are avoided.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `-e` is a GNU extension -- utterly and entirely incompatible with either XSI or non-XSI versions of POSIX-standardized `echo` (the former of which will process backslash-escapes without it and print the `-e` in its output if given, and the latter of which doesn't support them at all).

Comment: ...see the APPLICATION USAGE section of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Thanks I added a comment about it. `printf` is definitely better here.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between what `\$` is doing and what `\t` is doing.

The shell is expanding variables in double-quoted strings when it sees `$` so you need to "escape" the `$` from the shell (that's what `\$` is doing). You can also use a single-quoted which doesn't expand variables.

`\t` on the other hand is "backslash escape" (to use the term the `echo` man page uses). There's nothing special about `\t` (in a double-quoted string) to the shell so it doesn't touch it. And, by default, echo doesn't process "backslash escapes". You need the `-e` flag to turn that on.

Many people think that `echo` with arguments is an abomination and shouldn't exist and using the `-e` flag is easily avoided by using `printf` instead (which does handle a number of "backslash escapes" in its format string).

So the `printf` version of this would be (note the lack of `\$` in the format string because of the single quotes).

```
printf 'The balance for user %s is:\t$5:00' "$USER"
```

Comment: This is the part where some grumbling about GNU echo supporting the blatantly POSIX-incompatible (not just nonstandardized, but impossible-to-support-while-being-compliant) `-e` argument is due. :)